# Joomla 2.5 How To show Smart Search results on their own page

Tags: joomla-2.5, smartsearch

It's me again with that old J2.5 site (see my previous Q [K2 and duplicated Open Graph tags](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/k2-and-duplicated-open-graph-tags)).

Client wanted to have Smart Search instead of good old simple Search, so I have created module in the right column of type Smart Search Module, and configured it's settings accordingly. But for the life of me I couldn't make smart search results show up on their own page, they always show up the same way they do when I use simple Search module. I made sure that all Search plugins are disabled, that Content - Smart Search plugin and all neccessary Finder plugins are enabled and configured correctly, but nothing helps. I also did extensive search on this problem here on JSE, and there are more than 40 Qs on Smart Search, but couldn't find anything applicable to my problem.

Does anyone know how to make Smart Search results show on their own page, not on page of regular Search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem can be solved if you create menu item of type Smart Search.

From my own experience with Joomla 2.5 I found it is ‘always’ necessary to create a menu item for the ‘Smart search’, otherwise the search just directs to one to the usual (old) search page. It doesn’t matter if you disable the ‘old’ search plugin, one is still directed to the ‘old’ search result.

Create a Menu Item from the 'Smart Search' category. NOTE: there is a category of Menu Item called "Search" and a different Category of Menu Item called 'Smart Search'. Be sure you are in the category called 'Smart Search.' (To make it more confusing, the item itself is called 'Search' but just be sure you are in the 'Smart Search' category.)
After selecting this item type, in the Required Settings, choose your (optional) Search Filter and Save.

This menu item can be placed in a hidden menu if you do not desire a specific search page 
displayed on the site. The page doesn't have to exist on its own but it has to be there for the ‘smart search’ to operate properly within a module.

Note that I have not seen this peculiarity on Joomla 3.x which doesn’t require the menu item to be present.

Comment: Wooow... That was fast... @Zizela welcome to JSE and thank you so much, you answer solved my problem. I should have known better, but after two years of working exclusivelly in Joomla 3.x, it seems I started forgeting quirks of older Joomlas... Thanks agin...

Comment: You are welcome. I guess I was just lucky to stumble upon the question I know the answer so fast after my signup to JSE. I still have to browse around, it seems like a huge repository of Joomla gems.