# Smart Search always returning results to component, not the defined new page

Tags: joomla-3.x, smartsearch

I've read this: [Joomla 2.5 How To show Smart Search results on their own page](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/joomla-2-5-how-to-show-smart-search-results-on-their-own-page), but it seems to apply to J 2.5 only.

I've followed the steps here to set up Smart Search on a J 3.8.2 site: https://docs.joomla.org/Smart_Search_quickstart_guide

I created the Smart Search module and assigned it a position of "smart-search".

I then created an article with just the content `{loadposition smart-search}`.

I then created a "Search" menu item pointing to this article, its url is just `/smartsearch-2`, then went back to the module and set its `ItemID` to the new menu item.

When I select the menu, it takes me to this custom search page, i.e. my new article (/smartsearch-2), but when I enter a search term and click the search button there, the results are to what looks like the component page itself, i.e. the url is `/component/finder/search?q=&Itemid=246`.

I was expecting the search results to go back to the search page, i.e. `/smartsearch-2`, since that's what the setup guide says it does.

Have I misunderstood something here?

The (test) site is https://www.phonewebcam.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way that you created that menu item pointing to the article. You will need to create a menu item of type "Search" ("Smart Search"). This will ensure that the links are what you want them to be (note: you do **not** need to delete the menu item that you have created).

Note: It is a good idea to delete your test data and the data that came with your CMS (try searching for "test" on your site and you'll know what I mean).